# Get firebase registration token in SpringBoot java project

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, push-notification, expo

My serser uses Java with SpringBoot and my client is an expo react native app which uses typescript. I am really blocked by this feature: I want to sens push notifications. I tried a lot of methods, but I didn't succeed.

I tried to use Google FCM API to send the push notifications, but I noticed that I need the REGISTRATION TOKENS and I can't get them on the BE side.

In the official documentation is described the method, but using Android: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.

I have something like:

**The service**

```
@Service
public class FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY = server key from firebase project from cloud messaging section;
    private static final String FIREBASE_API_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<String> send(HttpEntity<String> entity) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        interceptors.add(new HeaderRequestInterceptor("Authorization", "key=" + FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY));
        interceptors.add(new HeaderRequestInterceptor("Content-Type", "application/json"));
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);

        String firebaseResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(FIREBASE_API_URL, entity, String.class);

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(firebaseResponse);
    }
}
```

And

**The Controller**

```
@Autowired
    FirebaseMessagingService firebaseMessagingService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> send(){

        JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
        body.put("to", "GM4nGHeift2zv4IDm9O75");
        body.put("priority", "high");

        JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
        notification.put("title", "JSA Notification");
        notification.put("body", "Happy Message!");

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("Key-1", "JSA Data 1");
        data.put("Key-2", "JSA Data 2");

        body.put("notification", notification);
        body.put("data", data);

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(body.toString());

        CompletableFuture<String> pushNotification = firebaseMessagingService.send(request);
        CompletableFuture.allOf(pushNotification).join();

        try {
            String firebaseResponse = pushNotification.get();

            return new ResponseEntity<>(firebaseResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>("Push Notification ERROR!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

When I try to send a notification, I receive the following error:

```
{
  "multicast_id": 385944902818046340,
  "success": 0,
  "failure": 1,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    }
  ]
}
```

Do you have any idea about how should I proceed to get the registration tokens on a Java project and send push notifications to my Expo client?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> my client is an expo react native app

Since FCM registration token is specific to each device/app combination, you'll need to get it inside your React Native app.

If you're using the regular JavaScript SDK for Firebase, follow the documentation on [accessing the registration token in the JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token).

If you're using the [React Native Firebase library](https://rnfirebase.io/), follow the instructions [here](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/messaging#getToken) and here: [Get FCM token in React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57140028/get-fcm-token-in-react-native)

Once you have the token, you can send it to your server, where you can then use it to send messages to that specific device/app combination.

Comment: Sounds good, but I have an Expo project and I tried but unfortunately the above methods were not compatible :( I tried to use both react native firebase library and  JavaScript SDK for Firebase but I didn't succedd. :(

Comment: Unfortunately Expo doesn't help me....I tried the https://expo.dev/notifications to send notifications and it worked. But as token I used something like an Expo token generated from my expo project: "Expo[-*******8...]". I can't understand how I could make them communicate...